# Repairing replaced OpenSSL installation

Tags: linux, centos, yum, openssl, rpm

I previously replaced openssl on my centos box with openssl10, using something like [these instructions](http://www.abstractpath.com/2014/updating-openssl-to-install-postgres-9-x-on-centos-6-x/):

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/...
     ...x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
yum install yum-plugin-replace
# Edit /etc/yum.repos.d/ius-archive.repo and 
# enable the ius-archive repo by changing enabled=0 to enabled=1.
yum replace openssl --replace-with openssl10
```

Then when I do a general `yum update` I get errors because of openssl, so instead I do:

```
yum update -x openssl -x postfix
```

This seems to work fine, but in actual fact, I can no longer reconnect over ssh to the box:

```
me@local $ ssh -S none root@the_server
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Any ideas on how to recover from this situation?

Edit:
When I run `sshd` on the server (I still have an open connection), I get the following error:

```
ssh: relocation error: ssh: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 
    not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference
```

Comment: Don't try to _replace_ the system OpenSSL. Just don't. You will break practically everything on the system. And I don't recommend the IUS repos either, since they seem to recommend various ways of breaking your system...

Comment: I agree with that sentiment now! Won't help with this question, but do you know of a better way of getting the latest version of openssl? My motivation was installation of SPDY on nginx.

Comment: I think that you are having an issue related to OpenSSL being upgraded in CentOS 6.5. If this is the case, [the solution is here](http://serverfault.com/q/563051/126632).

Comment: https://lists.launchpad.net/ius-community/msg00807.html explains how to resolve it and why you shouldn't have to use it anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a bug when using IUS repositories and using it to replace `openssl` with `openssl10` and then trying to upgrade to CentOS 6.5.

Basically what you have to do is go back to the stock `openssl` - which now is anyway on version 1.0.1:

```
yum replace openssl10 --replace-with openssl
```

Use of `openssl10` is unnecessary now and unsupported.
That is also why it is only available in the archive repo.

For more information see: https://lists.launchpad.net/ius-community/msg00807.html and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ius/+bug/1034961/comments/60

Comment: This is likely the right answer, however I'm getting `Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected` when I try to run yum replace.

Comment: Dependencies are `openssl10 -> python-libs -> pygpgme -> yum`
http://pastebin.com/ymAgZgQP

Answer (score 4):

Answer from @faker should be tried first, but if that doesn't work I found the following instructions at [rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-install-additional-options.html)

If you want to be on the safe side, also download rpms of yum and all it's dependencies

(Replace  with the exact one appropriate for your installation)

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-<version>.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-devel-<version>.rpm

rpm -i openssl-*
    file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
    .... lots more lines
```

Now take a backup of all those conflicting files in such a way as you can reinstate them to their correct folder if something goes wrong.

Finally, you can take a leap and do:

```
rpm  -iv --replacepkgs --replacefiles openssl-*
```

If all goes well `yum update` should work.

Edit: also erase the packages so that they don't conflict on future updates:

```
rpm -qa |grep ius
... lists packages
rpm -e openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
rpm -e openssl10-devel-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution to the above issue

```
yum update openssl openssl-devel
```

Comment: Solved in RHEL 7