# sshd installation broken. Repair with only file system access

Tags: ssh, remote-access, openssl, reinstall

I broke the sshd installation on a remote host and now ssh doesn't startup.
I can mount the file system on the host through a rescue system.

The rescue system is debian based and the host system is centos
I'm currently investigating repairing using yum:

```
apt-get install yum
chroot /mnt/rescue yum install --installroot=/mnt/rescue/ openssl
```

But I'm running into problems as $releasever isn't defined, and it doesn't recognize  mirrorlist.txt (`no valid mirrors`)

I'm wondering if there are any other options, e.g. placing a lightweight standalone ssh programme [e.g. dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) in /etc/init.d which will allow a login upon the next reboot?
Or should I persist with the `yum` approach?

Comment: **How exactly is it broken?**  What did you change.

Comment: That looks somewhat odd. You shouldn't need to install yum or use `--installroot`. Rather `mount -t proc none /mnt/rescue/proc; mount -o bind /dev /mnt/rescue/dev; chroot /mnt/rescue /bin/bash; yum install openssl` However, yum may depend on openssl so if that is what you fubar'ed you may not be able to use this.

Comment: @MarkWagner that comment has gotten me in to the right context. Do you want to write it up as an answer?

Comment: @Zoredache https://serverfault.com/questions/580854/