# Installing perl-Time-HiRes on RHEL6.2 gives perl dependency error

Tags: redhat, yum, perl

I get the following when trying to install perl-Time-HiRes:

```
host1:user1 > sudo yum install perl-Time-HiRes
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9721-119.el6_1.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl = 4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1 for package: 4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9721-119.el6_1.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9721-119.el6_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-6-6.2-server)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-129.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-129.el6
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-6-6.2-server)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I don't understand. It seems to be looking for perl-5.10.1-129? But the latest available is perl-5.10.1-119, as far as I can tell.

I have the EPEL repos enabled, though this package is from the repo `rhel-6-6.2-server`.

I am actually trying to install `munin-node`, but it fails on the same package.

Comment: It is looking for perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1. Note the trailing _1.1.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. But I can't seem to upgrade perl to that. `yum update perl` says it is up to date.

Comment: You should be using `upgrade` rather than `update` I suspect something is obsoleted.

Comment: If you mean to be on RHEL 6.2 (bad idea) why did you install 6.4?

Comment: @MichaelHampton good spot! Turns out I am actually on 6.4, but it was configured to use the 6.2 repos (guess a mistake when the server was built for me). Using the 6.4 repos worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: (And if you're using EPEL or any other third party repos, [you really should be on 6.5.](http://serverfault.com/a/563055/126632))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spotted by @MichaelHampton, I am actually using 6.4, but it was configured to use the 6.2 repos (guess a mistake when the server was built for me). Using the 6.4 repos worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment but I don't have enough points...

I've seen similar problems when doing yum updates.  (and it is yum update not yum upgrade).

Usually, this is easily resolved by doing a "yum update ", i.e. "yum update perl" then, if that succeeds, do the "yum update perl-Time-HiRes"