# How to solve multlib error?

Tags: centos, yum, openssl

I've been developing on a local Ubuntu Server, and moving dev files to production CentOS6 server.
Working on installing node,

The internet instructed to install the "development tools" group, so I did
and later learned I could just yum install npm, much like the deb apt-get.

yum install npm results in

```
Protected multilib versions: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686 != openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64
```

I've checked and I only have openssl.x86_64

Digging deeper into the web I think it's a problem with my updated php and sql being remi?
Updated php and mysql with instructions somewhere on the web.

```
$ rpm -q mysql-libs php-cli php
-----------------------------------
mysql-libs-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-5.4.29-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

I've attempted to downgrade openssl with same fail.
I attempted yum clean

Yum distro-sync gives me

```
 Error: Package: mysql-libs-5.5.37-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
       Removing: openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64 (@/openssl-1.0.1e-15.el6.x86_64)
           libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
       Downgraded By: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 (updates)
           Not found
```

I seem to be much better at Ubuntu than CentOS.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue, and get my yum to play nicely again?

**Edit**

Possible error in configs?
Here are links to files.

[weskamouse.net/conf : url to readable files](http://weskamouse.net/conf)

Willing to post more, just unsure what's needed.

Comment: Something's misconfigured with your system. Look for disabled repositories and inappropriate `exclude`s in the yum configuration.

Comment: I've ran `repolist all` and received [weskamouse.net/repolist.html](http://www.weskamouse.net/repolist.html) . I don't know what to make of it though =/

Comment: That's .... rather messy. So most likely you either have something excluded in `yum.conf` or your `CentOS-Base.repo` has been tampered with.

Comment: Any advice on what I should be looking for? in my base.repo the only enabled=0 is under [centosplus]. I really think that this is all caused by installing the "Development Tools" group. Is there anything to remove the development tools?

Comment: But I already told you what to look for and where!

Comment: Just anything excluded? I find that vague but I'm new and I don't want to mess things up further. I'll keep searching the internet.

Comment: If you don't want to read the files for themselves, at least paste them here so others can look at them.

Comment: I'm reading them, like I said I'm new I just don't know what to look for. I'll be adding links to these files in my post right now.

Comment: Ah, that confirms it. You are on GoDaddy and they have tampered with your `CentOS-Base.repo`. I've previously written [more information and instructions for fixing it](http://serverfault.com/a/563055/126632).

Comment: After closely examining your answer, I managed to update via a centos mirror, but still cannot distro-sync, downgrade openssl, or install npm. =/

Comment: If you replaced the `centos-release` RPM with a pristine copy, and the `CentOS-Base.repo` is correct and has no reference to GoDaddy servers, and you still couldn't run `yum distro-sync` then you may be having another issue. Try all of the above and if you have trouble, please ask a new question.