# How do I make PHP store sessions in redis on RHEL/CentOS?

Tags: php, node.js, redis, session, rhel7

Have some development and staging VM's running RHEL 7.2 with PHP5.6 via webtatic repo.

Have both Apache w/PHP and Node.js running fine.  Have redis deamon running fine.

Have not found a good best practice for enabling PHP to store sessions in redis.  I see reference to phpredis, but it looks like it needs to be build from source?  ... predis?  ... not an RPM via yum?

- php-nrk-Predis ?
- php-pecl-redis ?
- or just edit php.ini raw?
- Some combination of the above?

Ultimate Goal: enable both Apache/PHP and Node.js to share session in redis on same dev instance

Comment: Or just write a session handler: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since RHEL/CentOS 7.2 doesn't have direct PHP 5.6 support, using webtatic repo (for better or for worse) for now ... this seemed to do the trick.

```
# yum install redis

# yum install  php56w-pecl-redis

# diff /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

23,25c23,28
< php_value session.save_handler "files"
< php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"
< php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
---
> # p_value session.save_handler "files"
> php_value session.save_handler "redis"
> # p_value session.save_path    "/lib/php/session"
> php_value session.save_path    "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
> # p_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "/var/lib/php/wsdlcache"
> php_value soap.wsdl_cache_dir  "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"

# systemctl restart redis

# systemctl restart httpd
```

It's important to be very sure the correct PHP override directive is active since /etc/php.ini did NOT activate this, /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.ini did.  Browsing a test.php file with call to phpinfo(); quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You really only have one choice.

nrk/Predis is a PHP class which allows you to write programs that can read and write objects to Redis. This isn't what you're looking for here (though you may find it useful elsewhere).

phpredis/phpredis and php-pecl-redis are exactly the same thing. This *is* what you are looking for; it allows PHP to store sessions in redis. Keep in mind that you have to edit your php.ini or an included file to specify to store sessions in redis and provide connection information.

(And since you're interested in best practices, be aware that using webtatic *isn't* one. In most cases [you should be obtaining PHP](https://serverfault.com/a/749766/126632) from remi's repositories).

Comment: Excellent feedback.  I noticed that php-pecl-redis seemed to work, but didn't know it was essentially phpredis/phpredis.

Really getting tired of RH PHP being so old, will checkout remi

Comment: @rickatech Remi is the Red Hat employee who maintains RHEL's PHP packages (among others). His own repos contain later versions of PHP which are otherwise the same.

Comment: had a go using remi instead of webtastic repo for php5.6, pretty slick.  Nice write up on it at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-centos-7-0-x64